# Access denied when reading file in Images folder for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read the contents of an image file in my controller's Index action, but when I try to open the file, I receive the error 'access denied'. When I change the folder to 'Contents' it works. I don't want to duplicate the files in the Contents folder.

Is it possible to set the folder read/write permission in web.config?

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(
           Server.MapPath("~/Images/myimage.png"),
           FileMode.Open)
{
    // read stream
}
```

UnauthorizedAccessException error message:
Access to the path 'C:\TFS\ProjTest\Images\myimage.png' is denied.

Comment: Try specifying the FileAccess.Read parameter to the FileStream constructor.

Comment: Yes, @Joe, it works... Thank you for your help. Still, is it possible to set the read/write permission in web.config?

Comment: no... permissions are at the OS level, web.config is at the app level...

Comment: You should be able to setup the config the way you want it.  Then read the config value in code, and set a FileMode variable to the value you want; then use that variable in the FileStream constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a web.config setting, it's a system security setting.

On the windows system on which the application is hosted, you can change the security settings of the files that you are interested in accessing from your web application to give IIS_IUSRS group read/write access.  IIS_IUSRS typically only has Read access.  This group is the default group that IIS runs application as.  I'm not sure about what it runs as if you are using Visual Studio.

However, I would follow Joe's advice and open it as read only unless you intend on modifying the image.